# Execute a flyway callback in command line

Tags: java, callback, command-line-interface, database-migration, flyway

I use flyway command-line in a docker container to apply my migration scripts. I now have to add a Java callback in my implementation. The callback can successfully be detected and launch through the flyway-maven-plugin, with a `<callback>` definition in the `pom.xml`. I generate a JAR of this project.

I now want to run it with the command line. The following command works, my SQL migrations are applied

```
flyway repair migrate 
    -locations=path/to/sql/migration
    -url=...
```

If I add my callback, in this way, it tells me the following error

```
flyway repair migrate 
    -locations=path/to/sql/migration 
    -callbacks=com.company.MyCallback
    -url=...
```

*Unable to instantiate class "com.company.MyCallback"*

I also tried the jarDirs option, but same error

```
flyway repair migrate 
    -locations=path/to/sql/migration 
    -jarDirs=/folder/containing/the/jar/i/generated
    -callbacks=com.company.MyCallback
    -url=...
```

But no result. Any help or hint will be appreciated!

Comment: Run with debug option on `-X` to see where it is searching for migration files and jars.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, `-jarDirs` switch is supported for both repair and migrate commands that you are trying for and the documentation states

> jarDirs   Default:{install-dir}/jars  Comma-separated list of directories containing JDBC drivers and Java-based migrations

But this did not work in loading Custom Callbacks. Custom Callbacks seems to be loaded from `${FLYWAY_HOME}/jars` only.

I did some testing with a simple callback that extends from `org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.BaseFlywayCallback` and it seemed to work fine.

Hope this will solve your issue.